# Using chrome.tabs.executeScript when the tab changes URL or reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension and I want to inject and run Javascript code into a tab.

For example :

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(selectedTab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(selectedTab[0].id, {code: code_});
});
```

With the `code_` variable being :

```
$('#gbqfq').val('test');
$("#gbqf").submit();

$('#rso > div.srg > li:nth-child(1) > div > h3 > a').click();
```

This simple script is meant to be executed on google.com and should type and search "test" and click on the first result.

The problem is that after submitting the request, the tab changes its URL and thus loads another page. And it seems that when the page loads, all the scripts injected by `chrome.tabs.executeScript` disapears.

Is there a way to run a single script through different pages in the same tab ?

My extension should allow the user to run his own script, so it is complicated (maybe impossible?) to know in advance at which point of the script the tab is expected to reload (in order to use several `chrome.tabs.executeScript` calls).

Here is the manifest.json of my Extension, I am only using a popup (no background, no content_scripts) :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    ...

    "options_page": "options.html",

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "tabs",
        "windows",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot run *the same script* after a tab navigates away, since the JavaScript context in which the script lives is torn down.

So you will need to inject a script again after the page loads.
You probably want to do something along these lines:

1. Inject your submitting script and save the tab ID.
2. Initiate a submit.
3. Listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` filtered by tab ID above and status `"complete"`.
4. Check that the URL is the one you expected, then inject your data-gathering script.

Comment: Is there a way to know at which point the script is when `onUpdated` is fired ? As I said, I cannot know where in the script a navigation is expected.

Comment: At the point of `onUpdated`, the (content) script no longer exists.

Comment: All in all, your question seems to be very broad, by the way, if you're interpreting arbitrary user code.

Comment: Indeed, the point of the extension is to interpret any user scripts. I guess I'll try to implement a keyword that the user will have to write in his script to notify that the page is likely to navigate at the keyword's point.

Comment: If you want to go _all the way_, you should probably use content scripts as proxies only, and execute and keep local state in the background page. It would allow the user scripts to initiate navigation, then you block the call until the navigation completes, and resume running the script. That depends on the type of scripting you allow, though. If that starts to sound like a virtual machine because it essentially starts to become one.

Comment: I implemented the keyword to notify a page load, it works when I keep the popup alive thanks to the "Inspect the popup" option, but if I don't keep the popup alive, the script is interrupted. Should I use content_scripts or a background script ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61988/discussion-between-seeven-byakko-and-xan).